# Issue with a single project losing it's reference to SL/WP7 libs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have an issue where all my xaml views are saying there is a bad reference to System.Windows.dll.  I ran ProcMon and realized it was looking for the dll's in the GAC.  I started a new project, and it's looking for the dll's in the right spot (the Windows Phone 7 Referenced Assemblies folder).

All of my other projects are referencing fine (but this is the only one with views in this solution, other views work fine in other solutions).  I'm pretty sure it's something to do with VS2010's assembly cache, or possibly SxS, but I can't figure it out.

Anyone have an idea?  I don't want to GAC the libs, since that'll bring up other errors, I just want it restored to the way it was.

Here's the error I see in code for all my xaml pages.

Warning 1   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\MySln\MyApp\App.xaml    1   1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just expand the References folder in your project and remove the defunct reference and add the right one?!

Comment: Nope...  There's a reference cache somewhere that's telling VS to point to the GAC for that project.  I can't even remove the project and create one with the same name and have it work. It's definatly something local, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

Comment: Is the assembly marked with a yellow exclamation mark in the references folder? Could you perhaps share a screenshot of that. Also try to clean the complete solution and do a complete rebuild of the solution.

Comment: If it was that easy... You'd think I'd check that before I busted out procmon to determine where VS was trying to look for the assembly.  The project and solution see it as a reconized reference, there's something else.  It's looking in the GAC even if I put a hint path in the project file to the right path.

Comment: could it be that you are including a library that is build within a different framework like mentioned in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599842/missing-system-windows